# Приложение использует библиотеки не подходящей разрядности

Tags: windows, dll

В общем то при запуске приложения я получаю ошибку 0xc000007b связанную с несовместимостью разрядности приложения и dll библиотек которые использует приложение. То есть 64 бит игра использует библиотеки system32, то есть windows 32 бит, хотя у меня windows x64. Как заставить игру запускать библиотеки из syswow64, то есть от windows 64, а не windows 32

Comment: У тебя чистая винда или васянская сборка?